# Windows batch code to merge file and edit

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a lot of csv file into a folder.
The files are named like `OPERATORS_*.csv` where `*` is a variable.

I want, using a batch file, to merge all files into one, delete the first row of each file and add at the end of each row the `*`.

I have tried this code:

```
copy /b OPERATORS_*.csv OPERATORS_FULL.csv
```

This way is fine, but the first row of each file is printed and i lost the attribute in the filename.

Example:

OPERATORS_ACTIVITY1.csv

```
OPT;SALES;REDEMPTION
OPT1;12;75
```

OPERATORS_ACTIVITY2.csv

```
OPT;SALES;REDEMPTION
OPT2;22;64
```

and i want this:

OPERATORS_FULL.csv

```
OPT1;12;75;ACTIVITY1
OPT2;22;64;ACTIVITY2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does each input file contain a single line besides the headline only, or could there also be more lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this *(Update #2)*:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST OPERATORS_FULL.csv DEL OPERATORS_FULL.csv
IF EXIST OPERATORS_FULL.tmp DEL OPERATORS_FULL.tmp

FOR %%A IN ( OPERATORS_*.csv ) DO (
    :: get attribute from filename
    SET "attr=%%A"
    SET "attr=!attr:OPERATORS_=!"
    SET "attr=!attr:.csv=!"
    :: get date suffix
    SET tmp=!attr:_= !
    FOR %%G IN ( !tmp! ) DO (
        SET date_=%%G
    )
    :: if we have a date (i.e. a numeric value)
    IF !date_! EQU +!date_! (
        :: ...remove date from attr with leading underscore
        CALL SET attr=%%attr:_!date_!=%%
    ) ELSE (
        :: ...else clear date variable
        SET date_=
    )
    :: dump CSVs, skipping each header line, adding the attribute from the filename
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%G IN ( %%A ) DO ECHO %%G;!attr!;!date_! >> OPERATORS_FULL.tmp
)

REN OPERATORS_FULL.tmp OPERATORS_FULL.csv
```

Comment: Great! This works fine. Sometimes the end of the filename is ACTIVITY1_20170310. It is possible to split and then add the date at the end of the row?

Comment: I tried your code. It works fine if I have a static "attr" variable. But it can be APP_MKT_SELLING_yyyymmdd or MKT_yyyymmdd ...The date is ALWAYS the last item. The other are very ... "variable" :D

Comment: @TedGatiss: Can we assume if there is a second `_` in the filename, that a date is present? Or are there files named like this `OPERATORS_APP_WHATEVER.csv`?

Comment: it can be OPERATORS_APP_MKT_XXX_yyyymmdd or can be OPERATORS_APP_XXX_yyyymmdd... there is no standard number of "_"

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
del operators_full.csv 2>nul >nul 
FOR %%f IN (operators_*.csv) DO for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%%f") do echo %%a>operators_full.txt&goto body
:body
(
FOR %%f IN (operators_*.csv) DO FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%s IN ("%%~nf") DO for /f "skip=1usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%%f") do echo %%a;%%t
)>>operators_full.txt

move operators_full.txt operators_full.csv
```

First, delete the output file if it exists, then start copying the file(s) to a `.txt` file but deliberately abort after the very first line.

then, for each file, tokenise on the `_` in the name part of the file `%%f` copy every line,appending the post-`_` part of the filename in `%%t`, `skip`ping the first and append to the `.txt` file (note the position of the outer pair of parentheses - this syntax allows the output of the entire code block to be redirected)

Finally, move or rename the file.

Oh -- you don't want  the header line? Omit the first `for` line.

Comment: @aschipfl : Quite correct. adjusted to suit. Happens every time I don't actually check...

Comment: @zb226 : - oh - so now you want me to actually **read** the question as well? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pc4IFIXcDcs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using redirection -- see all the explanatory `rem` remarks in the script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INPUT=OPERATORS_*.csv"     & rem // (input files)
set "_OUTPUT=OPERATORS_FULL.csv" & rem // (output file)
set /A "_SKIP=1" & rem // (number of lines to skip for each input file)

rem // Redirect the whole output at once:
> "%_OUTPUT%" (
    rem // Iterate over all the input files:
    for %%F in ("%_INPUT%") do (
        rem // Store the current file name to get the attribute name later:
        set "NAME=%%~nF"
        rem // Exclude the output file from being processed:
        if /I not "%%~nxF"=="%_OUTPUT%" (
            rem // Determine the number of lines of the current input file:
            for /F %%E in ('^< "%%~F" find /C /V ""') do set /A "CNT=%%E"
            rem // Read current input file:
            < "%%~F" (
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem // Loop over every line:
                for /L %%E in (1,1,!CNT!) do (
                    rem // Read current line:
                    set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
                    rem // Return current line if it is not to be skipped:
                    if %%E GTR %_SKIP% echo(!LINE!;!NAME:*_=!
                )
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```